# A recursive formula to approximate $e$. Prove or disprove.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let the sequence $\{x_n, n=1,2,...\}$ be defined as follows: Let $x_2=x_1=1$
and for $n>2$ let
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{1}{n}x_{n-1}.$$

This sequence, generated by the recursion above, tends to zero extremely fast. My guess is that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i=e.$$

I came across this problem here on MSE [while working on an infinite Markov chain related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171283/finding-the-stationary-distribution/1171547#1171547). The state transition probability matrix was given and the task was to find the stationary probabilities. The stationary probabilities could be generated by the recursion above but with an unknown $c=x_1=x_2$. I did some experiments with $c$ and the results lead me believe that $$c=e.$$

I would be surprised if this recursion was not known to [somebody around](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171572/a-recursive-formula-to-approximate-e-prove-or-disprove) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recursion is satisfied by $$x_n=\frac{1}{\Gamma (n)}$$ So, $$\sum_{i=1}^p x_i=\frac{e\, p \,\Gamma (p,1)}{\Gamma (p+1)}$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function and the limit is effectively $e$.

Answer (score 8):

It can be proved by induction that $x_n = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

$x_1$ and $x_2$ satisfy this, and by doing induction,

$$x_{m+1} = x_{m}-\frac{1}{m}x_{m-1} = \frac{1}{(m-1)!} - \frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{(m-2)!} = \frac{1}{m!} $$

Thus you series reduces to the ordinary series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ for $e$

Answer (score 3):

The first terms of the sequence are
$$1,1,\frac12,\frac16,\frac1{24},\frac1{120}\cdots$$which you recognize without surprise.

Indeed, with $x_n=\dfrac1{(n-1)!}$ you have

$$x_n=nx_{n+1},$$
$$x_{n-1}=n(n-1)x_{n+1},$$
hence
$$x_n-\frac nn(n-1)x_{n-1}=x_{n+1}.$$

Nothing new, sorry.

Comment: I knew, I knew.