# Recursive formula for e

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, constants

Looking for a finite recursive formula for the constant e preferably using standard operators (ones a calculator could carry out)

i.e. a formula of the form $ x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$  where  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_n)=e$ for some $x_1$

Bonus points if it works for any $x_1$

Comment: $e=\lim(1+1/2!+\dots +1/n!)$

Comment: @TheG Sorry updated I'm looking for a finite formula

Comment: Do you mean $x_n=f(x_{n+1})$ or $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$?

Comment: lim as n approaches infinity of $(1+1/n)^n)$ is equal to $e$.

Comment: @N. Yes I did sorry!

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош  That's not recursive though, also most calculators can't do limits.

Comment: @andrew But you asked for the calculator to calculate $x_n$ and to have $$e=\lim x_n$$ A calculator can definitely calculate $\left(1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$.

Comment: @andrew By recursive formula you mean formula for finding better and better approximations of $e$ ? Because, I know recursive formula as the way of defining sequence but not defining a number.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171572/a-recursive-formula-to-approximate-e-prove-or-disprove

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Yes, is a formula that finds better and better approximations of e not a recursive function?

Comment: @andrew You mean definition of e ? Definition of e is a limit of a sequence. For approximating $e$ you can take limit definition of it and substitute big value of $n$.

Comment: In addition to my answer, I'd also like to point out that this question has been looked at [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171572/a-recursive-formula-to-approximate-e-prove-or-disprove).

Comment: You could be interested to my question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2622195

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2629616

Comment: @Brain this was linked in a comment above and looks quite interesting but I'd really like a sequence which only has the $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ terms.

Comment: @Fabio This first relation given in the second question you linked looks interesting but didn't seem to work for the couple numbers I tried for $a_1$, have I made some kind of mistake or is there a set range of values $a_1$ can take?

Comment: @andrew: You are right there is a mistake in the formula; I edited it now.

Comment: @Fabio does this not just tend to infinity?

Comment: Yes, the left handed sequence diverges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use Newton's method on a function known to have a zero at $e$—for instance, $f(x) = \ln x - 1$.  Then $f'(x) = 1/x$, and we can iterate as

$$
x_{n+1} = x_n (2-\ln x_n)
$$

Of course, this isn't very satisfying, since the natural log is sitting right there in the expression.  (I also haven't looked at the interval of convergence.)  But it is available on most scientific calculators.

I'll have to give this more thought to see if something clever can be done to avoid the natural log (or exp, for that matter).

---

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, this question has been looked at [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171572/a-recursive-formula-to-approximate-e-prove-or-disprove) on Math.SE, with the nice result

$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac1n x_{n-1}
$$

with $x_1 = x_2 = 1$.  This is not *exactly* in the form desired by the OP, but it's pretty nice all the same.

Comment: Newton's method is the reason I started thinking about this but I couldn't think of any functions with roots at e. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$$x_{n+1}= \left( 1+ \frac{\max\{ |x_n|,1 \} }{n}\right)^{\frac{\max\{ |x_n|,1 \}}{n}}$$